# Algorithm for randomly laying out objects on a lattice

Tags: algorithm

What would be a good way to randomly place a list of m-by-k objects on a rectangular lattice while keeping the distribution uniform and avoiding collision?

Here is an example:

> List of objects: `11111, 111, 1111, 11`
>
> possible configuration on a 7x7 lattice:
>
> ```
> 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
> 1 0 1 1 0 0 1
> 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
> 0 1 1 1 1 0 1
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
> ```

What I have done so far:

I wrote a code to generate random configurations and then check for collisions and rejects/accepts the configuration. It takes a bit to run and I'm looking for better ways to do it.

Comment: does the runtime complexity matter? (e.g. maximum `O(nlogn)`)

Comment: @Leonardo nlogn would be affordable.

Comment: How big of a lattice are you going to do this with? How many objects, and of what size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about keeping the distribution uniform, but this is random as much as I can think of right now and will avoid collisions:

```
While items in itemBucket:
    item = getNextItem()

    legalPosition = false
    While not legalPosition:
        newPosition = choose random location/position
        legalPosition = isPositionLegal(newPosition)
```

This way, by picking the items one at a time and then setting & validating them one at a time you are sure to get a valid positioning (unless you position the first items such that there is no way to do it at all)